# Tracking the spawned threads in ThreadPoolExecutor java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am spawning 5 threads by using a threadpool. Now i would like to know the best way of tracking all these threads and capturing the metrics of each thread like

- How much time each thread took?
- How much memory each thread utilized?

Do we have any ready made implementations which does the job for us. Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadPoolExecutor executors = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        System.out.println("at executors step");
        List<String> getlist = getList();
        for (Iterator<String> itr = getlist.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
            String element = (String) itr.next();
            String[] command = { "ssh", "hddev-c01-edge-02", "\"" + element + "\"" };
            System.out.println("the command is as below ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(command));
            System.out.println("inside the iterator");
            ParallelExecutor pe = new ParallelExecutor(command);
            executors.execute(pe);
        }
        executors.shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: Memory will be difficult to measure, as heap memory is shared between all threads and managed in the background by a garbage collector.

Comment: Is it possible to track the thread if not the memory?

Comment: Why use an `Iterator` when a foreach loop would be both simpler and clearer? P.S. also, use a Java SSH library rather than running random external processes.

Comment: To answer your question: use a profiler. For example [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) which ships with the JDK.

Comment: Hi Boris, As your rightly pointed. I agree with you using a foreach loop would be simpler but i usually use Iterator so somewhat biased :)

Comment: Using a particular construct because you usually do, even when it's not the best solution to a problem, is a horrible coding habit that you need to get out of.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods in ThreadPoolExecutor which you can override to do this kind of house keeping, like how much time a thread took to execute a Runnable.
Extend the ThreadPoolExecutor and override only 2 methods like,

```
protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) { }

protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) { }
```

Hope this helps.